# Return fictive edges from Gremlin query

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

I have a graph with the following vertices and edges for example:
A->B->C
and I want to write a gremlin query that will return a path like A->C so it will be visualized in the Jupyter notebook I'm using ([aws-notebooks-visualization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/notebooks-visualization.html).
This means returning a fictive edge from A to C although it doesn't really exist in the original graph.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where `flatMap` can help. Given this graph:

```java
g.addV('A').as('a').
  addV('B').as('b').
  addV('C').as('c').
  addE('link').from('a').to('b').
  addE('link').from('b').to('c')
```

The following query will generate the result you are looking for:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('A').
  flatMap(out().out()).
  path().
    by(elementMap())
```

[image]